# How to disable the Spring Boot 2 Actuator discovery page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

As explained in the [Spring Boot 2.0 Actuator docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-hypermedia), Spring automatically generates a discovery page at the configured Actuator base path.

However, I have my own overview page mapped at that same base path. Because the Actuator endpoint mappings have a higher priority than my own mappings, I cannot override the mapping.

Is there a way to disable the generation of this discovery page by Spring Boot?

The documentation only mentions that the page is disabled when setting the management context path to '/', but that's not an option for me (this would require a lot of endpoint remappings).

Answer (score 0):

You could update the management.context-path to some other path.  Something like this

> management.context-path=/someOtherActuatorPath

Your discovery page would now be on /someOtherActuatorPath